# Varnish resetting after a while despite setting TTL to 0

Tags: varnish

I am doing some banning tests for the cache.

Of course I don't want false positives, so I've set:

```
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
```

on my default.vcl file and reset the service.

Despite that, after a minute of two, the cache is refreshed.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following your question, but `beresp.ttl = 0s` means disabling caching (at least if built-in VCL is executed you'll cache a HFP/HFM object; otherwise is a bad idea due to request serialisation).

Comment: It did not disable my cache but just in case I just set the cache to 100 years unless banned and I'm good to go.